# Installing jdk meant for linux on OS X

Tags: java, linux, macos, java-6

I was trying to find a [download for jdk 1.6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) specifically for OS X. But Oracle doesn't seem to offer one. This made me wonder if the jdk 1.6 meant for Linux would work fine on OS X. I could try running it to see if it works. But I thought I'd check here to see if there are any subtle or not-so-subtle issues that I've missed.

I have an AMD-64 architecture on my mac system.

Comment: I am from the future and am wondering this too. Did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 6 for Mac is provided by Apple rather than Oracle, and can be downloaded from http://support.apple.com/downloads/#Java - look for the latest "Java for OSX", which at the time of writing is [2014-001](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).